# Render ApexCharts PNG file in the backend?

Tags: angular, backend, nestjs, social-media, apexcharts

In ApexCharts toolbar there is an option to download the chart as a PNG file. Is there any way to do the same in a NestJs (or Node) backend to automatically produce static PNG files, to use those static images in meta tags for open graph and social sharing?

Update: It appears that the charting library heavily depends on a Browser to render the graphs, and if I want to do this I need to run a browser (e.g. PhantomJs) in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any straightforward way to achieve this. However, apexcharts has a feature where you can install a separate server (FusionExport) and call it to render a chart as an image or a PDF file. You can find more information about it [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/export-to-pdf-in-php/).
But this is a paid solution.

If this does not suit you, you could implement a headless browser like [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and use a library like [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to call it.
Once that is set up, you could write a simple script to load a chart and take a screenshot once it has completed or you could use the following callback to generate an image (dataURI) from apexcharts itself.

```
chart.dataURI().then(({ imgURI, blob }) => {
  // use the imgURI as needed
})
```